# What changes can be made to a Paragraph style when associated with a Multi Level List

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have some Heading Styles defined that are associated to a multi Level List. Adjusting the Text Indent in Paragraph seems to work until the inden exceeds the List Indent then all sorts of weird things happen.

[image: List Definition]

If I set Paragraph based Indenting or Tabs once the level of Indent exceeds the Multilevel List Indent then it reverts to the List Indent. Likewise with Tabs.

Four questions

- Anyone know a good Tutorial on how to set Multilevel List formats to
  cater for large numbers, I'm in the 10's at level 2 & 3.
- How do I delete Multilevel List Formats that are of no use anymore.
- What Paragraph Formatting can I do at the STyle level that won't
  impact the List Formatting?
- Once I get the Multi Level List Formatting right how do I copy it to another document. I've defined a Template for documents but When I open a document that has had the Template attached in the Developer Tab the List format doesn't come across and I have to adjust it manually.